# Apple Pay Not valid when using Adhoc Distribution Provisional Profile

Tags: ios, xamarin, applepay

I have been developing apple pay in a Xamarin.iOS application. When calling `CanMakePaymentsUsingNetworks` in debug with the developer provisional profile, true is returned. However, when in release mode with an AdHoc Distribution Provisional Profile it returns false.

It maybe important to note that my iCloud account attached to my iOS device is a live account (not sandbox) and has live cards in it. Could this be impacting the result of the call?

When checking the logs I see the following entry:
`PKCanMakePaymentsUsingNetworksIssuerCountryCodesWithCapabilities (<private>, f) returns 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the following line was not included in the csproj file for the selected build environment, however it was in the Debug configuration:

`<CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>`